# Is it possible to deploy a python script to /cgi-bin/ on a heroku cedar stack alongside my ruby on rails application?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, heroku, cgi, cgi-bin

Right now I deploy a RoR app to passenger + apache2, and because of a legacy requirement I use a python .cgi script in the apache /cgi-bin/.

Is it possible to deploy a rails app to heroku with scripts in a /cgi-bin/?

Thanks!

Comment: It's possible (though unlikely) that the dyno doesn't even have Python installed! And even if it is, you might not be allowed to run it. If you need to use multiple languages, consider OpenShift instead of Heroku.